# Запрос на поиск по части текста

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Делаю выборку из базы данных mysql. Есть поля в которых нужно искать по точным вхождениям (тип INT). а есть текстовые, где нужно чтобы находило даже по одному слову.
Возможно ли это сделать с помощью такого запроса?

```
$item = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `id_item` FROM `x-ka` WHERE (id_pole, value) in ($in) GROUP BY `id_item` HAVING COUNT(`id_item`) = $hc");
```

Сейчас этот запрос ищет по точным вхождениям.

смотрите
мой запрос не ищет по всей таблице какое-то поле, к котором будет заданное пользователем значение. запрос ищет поля с определенным id , и у этого поля сверяет введенное значение
вот вопрос в том, как применить к нему like, учитывая то, что id полей, в которых нужно сверить введенное значение, может быть неопределенное кол-во
запрос который я написал в вопросе полностью справляется с этой задачей, но он делает выборку по точному вхождению( как сделать подобное с like , или может быть в mysql есть нечто что иное, что могло бы мне помочь с этим запросом.

Comment: а скажете по какому полю нужно искать вхождение слов?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan дело в том что в скрипте динамическое создание полей, но определить тип поля можно заранее. пусть для примера это будет `text`

Comment: Приводите больше данных, дайте структуру таблицы и скажите какой результат вы ожидаете?

Answer (score 1):

Для такого поиска что вы хотите сделать в MySQL есть `LIKE`․

Вот пример запроса с полем что вы сказали:

```
$item = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `id_item` FROM `x-ka` WHERE (id_pole, value) in ($in) AND `text` LIKE '%some word%' GROUP BY `id_item` HAVING COUNT(`id_item`) = $hc");
```

Где `some word` искоемая подстрока в поле `text`․

> Примечание: Функциа `mysql_query` устаревшая, лучше пользоваться классам [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: я знаю что есть like, дело в том, что как вы наверное заметили выборка идет по ключу ид-поля(записи в таблице) : значение. просто искать поле `text` по всей таблице не подходит

Comment: Вот для того и я говорил приводите больше данных, дайте структуру таблицы, и конкретно обясните то что вы хотите реализовать, и я изменю ответ.

Comment: есть динамическое создание фильтра для характеристик товара. поля могут быть типа int или varchar. если тип varhar - то должно искать на по подобии `like` . при создании поля характеристики создается отдельная запись в таблице `x-ka` . где *id_pole* - ид созданного поля, и `value` - его значение. при отправке запроса от пользователя я определяю id заданных полей, и делаю по ним выборку `WHERE (id_pole, value) in ($in)` - работает как нужно, но ищет только по точным вхождениям

Comment: @Денис подробности давайте в вопрос

Comment: я просто не знаю что можно еще подробнее изложить, все уже описал вроде)

Comment: Сейчас попробую понять и ответит

Comment: в фильтре заранее не определить сколько будет полей, так как они создаются динамически, через админку, а пользователь уже вводит параметры в созданные поля. и с этим отлично помогает запрос который я написал в вопросе, но он делает выборку значения именно по точным вхождениям.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59607/discussion-between-razmik-galstyan-and-).